# eclipse will not read my code, and displays the previous code

Tags: java, eclipse

I wrote a code using eclipse, and I am having trouble running it.  It shows up with no errors and everything seems to correct, but when I run it, my eclipse only runs the previous eclipse code i ran... so for example,

In eclipse, if i run an old code i wrote for name display that i wrote, and right now writing a separate code (both with main()) lets say for age, if i run name or any other previous written program from my eclipse, and it runs, and then i try to run the new age code, my eclipse only runs the previous code that i wrote.  the eclipse works with every other code except for the one I just wrote(example age).

What am i doing wrong or what is going on with my eclipse?  I even copied and emailed it to my self so i can open it on my other computer, but no execution on the other computer either....anybody know whats going on with my eclipse???

Comment: Try this: (In the menu bar) Select *Project* -> **Clean...** Then right-click your class, go on *Run as* -> *Java Application*

Comment: Terminate all running class , there is an icon on the console that does that , and then re-run