# Eclipse Console running old version of class file

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm running a JUnit file in a maven project on eclipse, and whenever I run the test, no matter what I comment out or change, the result is the same.

i.e., if I comment out all the code I still get everything I originally printed into the console.

I've tried these solutions so far and nothing works: 
[Deleting old versions of the class on "Run Configurations" the project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36860628/eclipse-running-old-version-of-java-program) 
[Saving/Cleaning the project and terminating classes already running on the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22212612/eclipse-will-not-read-my-code-and-displays-the-previous-code) 
[Checking and unchecking "build automatically" option and making sure there are no errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26206715/running-my-new-code-runs-my-old-code) 
[Deleting old files in the project output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706140/eclipse-keeps-running-my-old-web-application/4892156#4892156)

In the last option, I think that there might be more I can do but I don't know how/what that would be. What I have done there is directly go into my target folder and delete all the versions of the same class, then save the .java file on eclipse again (creating new class files of the new version in the output folder)

Nothing has worked. How do I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Seems like the files you are editing and the files Eclipse is compiling are different files. Check that your project is configured inside the right directory and that you are editing the right file.

Comment: @Roman, When I delete the class files and recompile them, there is only one copy in a target folder within the project. That should indicate that I am editing the right file in the right directory, or am I wrong?

Comment: Not necessarily: if you edit a file `.../aaa/X.java` and Eclipse's project is set up to track directory `.../bbb/` (not `.../aaa/`), then it will compile file `.../bbb/X.java` into `target/X.class`.